# Can gorm criteria constraint by realation domain Class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

Have a domain A110 it belong to A100.

I use createCriteria want to constraint by a100's column "noteDt"

```
A110.createCriteria().list() {
    order("A100.noteDt", "asc")// <--not work
}
```

I wonder is there any way in Gorm criteria can do this?

or other method in grails except raw sql code?

Comment: What is the name of the property in `A110` that references the owning `A100` instance?

Comment: name is A100~ thx u ,i got solution below :)

Comment: ` A100~` is not a valid property name.  Are both the class name and the property name `A100`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code --

```
A110.createCriteria().list() {
  A100 {
    order("noteDt", "asc")
  }
}
```

or

```
A110.createCriteria().list() {
  createAlias('A100', 'a100')
  order("a100.noteDt", "asc")
}
```